# phpmyadmin can't view databases on wamp

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

Windows 10 did some update and really jacked up lots of settings on my apps.  For some reason when I login into WAMP I can't see any of the databases.  If I click on localhost I can still see the websites that are running on the databases that I used to be able to see.  The websites run fine, but I can't see the databases.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not sure if this will help, but is the file path of where your databases are located still correct in phpMyAdmin?  If the file path has been altered or removed, this would explain the inability of phpMyAdmin to locate the databases.  I am glad you still have access to the databases.

Comment: What colour is the Wampmanager icon in the system tray?

Comment: Where can I see what the file path is for the databases for phpmyadmin?

Comment: The icon is green

Comment: @GKnight There is no file path. This is MYSQL and not a file bases database like sqlite. phpMyAdmin connects to MYSQL and MYSQL knows where the databases are located

Comment: My Guess is that you logged in to phpMyAdmin using a made up userid/password. If you have not changed the root accounts password then the login is **Username** = `root` **Password** = `leave this blank`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for the heads up, that makes sense.  I also think that your last comment may solve the problem.  Bad user info = No databases.